# Number of unique items in a group

Tags: python-polars

Given a dataframe, how do I count the number of [multi-column] unique records within a group, and return the result as a single column?

I'd like to do something like this:

```py
from datetime import date

import polars as pl
from polars import col

day1 = date(1982, 1, 14)
day2 = date(1984, 8, 30)
day3 = date(1992, 1, 8)
day4 = date(1999, 12, 31)
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "ID": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    "gender": ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
    "birth_dt": [day1, day1, day2, day2, day3, day3, day4, day4]
})
```

```py
df.select(col(["gender", "birth_dt"]).unique().count().over("ID")) # not quite what I want
```

```
shape: (8, 2)
┌────────┬──────────┐
│ gender ┆ birth_dt │
│ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ u32    ┆ u32      │
╞════════╪══════════╡
│ 2      ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2        │
└────────┴──────────┘
```

```py
df.groupby("ID").agg(col(["gender", "birth_dt"]).n_unique()) # also not quite what I want
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ ID  ┆ gender ┆ birth_dt │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ str ┆ u32    ┆ u32      │
╞═════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ B   ┆ 1      ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ 2      ┆ 2        │
└─────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

However, the `unique()` is called for each column individually. I'd like instead to return the number of unique `(gender, birth_dt)` combinations for each `ID`.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is to bind the columns of interest into a [`struct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.struct.html), and then count the unique items.  For example:

```py
(
    df
    .groupby("ID")
    .agg(
        pl.struct(['gender', 'birth_dt']).n_unique().alias('result')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ ID  ┆ result │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ str ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ A   ┆ 2      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ 2      │
└─────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks @cbilot. Is there a way to use this with `.over()` so that I can re-transform back to the original dataframe without using a join? Edit here we go: `df.select(pl.struct(["gender", "birth_dt"]).n_unique().over("ID"))`.