# Polars equivalent to SQL `COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])`, or other method of checking uniqueness

Tags: python-polars

When processing data, I often add a check after each step to validate that the data still has the unique key I think it does. For example, I might check that my data is still unique on `(a, b)`. To accomplish this, I would typically check that the number of distinct combinations of columns `a` and `b` equals the total number of rows.

In polars, to get a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` I can do

```py
(
  df
  .select(['a', 'b'])
  .unique()
  .height
)
```

But `height` does not work on `LazyFrame`s, so I need to actually materialize the entire data with this method, I think (?). Is there a better way?

For reference, in R's data.table library I would do

```
mtc_dt <- data.table::as.data.table(mtcars)
stopifnot(data.table::uniqueN(mtc_dt[, .(mpg, disp)]) == nrow(mtc_dt))
```

To any contributors reading:

Thanks for the great package! Has sped up many of my workflows to a fraction of the time.

Comment: Perhaps [`.is_unique()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_unique.html#polars.Expr.is_unique) could be used.

Comment: @jqurious I need it to work with > 1 column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `map` function that asserts on the unique count.

This allows you to get an eager `DataFrame` in the middle of a query plan.

Note that we turn off `projection_pushdown` optimization, as the optimizer is not able to know which subset of columns we select.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [1, 2, 3], 
    "bar": [None, "hello", None]
})


def unique_check(df: pl.DataFrame, subset: list[str]) -> pl.DataFrame:
    assert df.select(pl.struct(subset).unique().count()).item() == df.height
    
    return df


out = (df.lazy()
  .map(lambda df: unique_check(df, ["foo", "bar"]), projection_pushdown=False)
  .select("bar")
  .collect()
)

print(out)
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────┐
│ bar   │
│ ---   │
│ str   │
╞═══════╡
│ null  │
│ hello │
│ null  │
└───────┘
```

Not turning of `predicate_pushdown` is better, but then we must ensure the subset is selected before the `map`.

Comment: Thanks. Two questions (1) This assumes I know the total number of rows. What's the best way to get the total number of rows of a LazyFrame? (2) I still have to collect for the assertion to trigger right? Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Actually, I get error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'item' on python 3.6 polars 0.14.18

Comment: You still have to collect to run the query. If you don't want to collect, you also don't need an assert.

Comment: You must upgrade to latest polars.

Comment: Forget that first question, it didn't make much sense. Assume I have a (non-Lazy) DataFrame, and I just want to know if it is unique. It seems like this requires me to materialize a copy of at least a single column of my data. Is that true, and is there any way to avoid that? Like `data.table::uniqueN(<data.table>)` does not ever put a data.table in user-land, but still tells me how many unique rows there are.

Comment: I have update the answer to check if a subset is unique.

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74002026/2954547) provides a technique that can answer this question: gather the columns together in a struct column, and then apply `.n_unique()` to that struct. That question uses `groupby`, but it will work *without* `groupby` as well.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(pl.struct(['a', 'b'].alias('ident'))
    ['ident'].n_unique()
)
```

I was able to run code more or less identical to this on a dataset I am working with, and got a sensible answer.

Note that I am not sure if this materializes the entire table before aggregating, nor if this works specifically on lazy data frames. If not, please let me know, and I will retract this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4],'c':[3,4,5]}).lazy()
```

and you want to see if `[a,b]` are unique without returning all the data, you can lazily group by and count those groups.  With that, you can add a filter such that only rows with a count greater than 1 are returned.  Only after those expressions are strung to the LazyFrame do you collect and if your pair of columns remain unique as you intend then the result will have 0 rows.

```
df \
    .groupby(['a','b']) \
    .agg(pl.count()). \
    filter(pl.col('count')>1).select('count').collect().height
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `.count()` on a `LazyGroupBy`

Comment: You can `agg(pl.count())`